# FactoryGirl specifying create_list count for deeply nested association

Tags: factory-bot

The following is the association set-up:

- Categories has many Chapters
- Chapters has many Pages
- Pages have one Text or Audio

I would like to generate records at the Category level and to specify the number of Chapters, Pages, and an optional Text or Audio record.

I am aware of using create_list to specify the first level of associations (Chapters). Is there any way to specify the count for the deeper associations? Initial thought tells me to nest the after(:create). Would that be the correct approach?

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :category do
        ignore do
            chapters_count 1
        end

        trait :with_chapters do
            after(:create) do |instance, evaluator|
                create_list :chapter, evaluator.chapters_count, category: instance
            end
        end

        trait :with_chapters_and_pages do
            ...?
        end

        trait :with_chapters_and_pages_with_text do
            ...?
        end

        trait :with_chapters_and_pages_with_audio do
            ...?
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with FactoryGirl and reading the syntax/methods.rb code, I came up with a working solution. If others have a better approach, please share :)

```
# category_factory.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
    # Fields
    # --------------------------------------------------
    (...)

    # Transient Attributes
    # --------------------------------------------------
    ignore do
        chapter_count   1               # Number of associated Chapters to create
        page_count      1               # Number of Chapter associated Pages to create
        page_type       :with_text      # Page type either :with_text (default) or :with_audio
    end

    # Traits
    # --------------------------------------------------
    trait :with_chapter do
        after(:create) do |instance, evaluator|
            create_list :chapter, evaluator.chapter_count, category: instance
        end
    end

    trait :with_chapter_and_page do
        after(:create) do |instance, evaluator|
            create_list :chapter, evaluator.chapter_count, :with_page, category: instance, page_count: evaluator.page_count, page_type: evaluator.page_type
        end
    end
end

# chapter_factory.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
    # Fields
    # --------------------------------------------------
    (...)
    category

    # Transient Attributes
    # --------------------------------------------------
    ignore do
        page_count  1           # Number of Chapter associated pages to create
        page_type   :with_text  # Page type either :with_text (default) or :with_audio
    end

    # Traits
    # --------------------------------------------------
    trait :with_page do
        after(:create) do |instance, evaluator|
            create_list :page, evaluator.page_count, evaluator.page_type, chapter: instance
        end
    end
end

# page_factory.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
    # Fields
    # --------------------------------------------------
    (...)
    chapter

    # Traits
    # --------------------------------------------------
    trait :with_text do
        after(:create) do |instance, evaluator|
            create :text, page: instance
        end
    end

    trait :with_audio do
        after(:create) do |instance, evaluator|
            create :audio, page: instance
        end
    end
end

# text_factory.rb & audio_factory.rb
(...)
```

There is some repeat with the transient attributes. Not sure how to DRY it up...